# Percentage sum by category - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

How can acheive correct SUM %  please?  I have attahed PBIX file with data and example:

[Download PBIX](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zwtz1dc5qbfppmi/Percentage%20by%20category.pbix?dl=0)

[image]

Thanks you very much.

Comment: You want to SUM percentages?? I can help you with the calculation, but I have to first ask if you understand how mathematically dubious what you're wishing to do is? What would  the 33% for January actually represent, for you, in layman's terms?

Comment: Just to give you a hypothetical example of what I mean, imagine my company makes 2 cars, Model A and Model B, and let's say 1000 of Model A and 500 of Model B were manufactured in 2021, and that 200 of Model A and 500 of Model B were sold in 2021, i.e. 20% of Model A and 100% of Model B were sold. It would be perfectly normal and reasonable to also say that, across both models, (200+500)/(1000+500), i.e. 700/1500, i.e. 47% of those manufactured were sold. However, your desired measure would be to take 100%+20%, i.e. 120%, though I can't even think of what this might represent. 120% of what?

Comment: @JosWoolley Thanks for your response.  Actually Percentage shown is a part of a bigger calculation for which users want to see the SUM per category.  To make it simple and without complicating my requirement,  I did a simple calculation.  Numbers are stupid but there is purpose behind it.  Hope this helps?  Please can you share your PBIX file if you managed to sum the % and Chart also show required %s by month please.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this measure

```
Measure2 =
SUMX (
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        CROSSJOIN ( 'Calendar', 'Product Group' ),
        "diff", [Percentage Diff]
    ),
    [Percentage Diff]
)
```

[image: s1]

Comment: You are a star. This worked. can you explain what crossjoin did and why you have used it please? I am new to DAX so want to understand. Thanks much

Comment: In the viz, you brought two axis->`Calendar`[Month Name] and `'Product Group'[Product Group]`. They have no relationship between them but each of them filters other Fact tables -> Forecast and Sales. The measure that you created already works but since there is no relationship exists a `CROSSJOIN` is required which is basically multiplying each row on t1 with each row of t2. Once I have that and add a column by dropping the already created measure, SUMX is ready to give the total of diff as you desired.

Comment: This is brilliant!  Thank you for solving and explaining the logic. much appreciated.  Do you recommend any courses/videos to learn DAX to build solid basics?  SQLBI is great but I find them too complicated and advanced to learn.  Also are you ok to tag you for any future queries I may have -- totally understand it might not be possible to respond to each and every query.

Comment: The best resource for learning DAX is SQLBI but it is definitely requires you to be a bit fluent with DAX first in order to understand the concept the way they explain. I found DAX very tough when I started with it. The only way I became more fluent with it was by participating in Power BI community (hands down the best place for any Activist learner as opposed to Theorist) and in stackoverflow (stack has way lesser traffic for DAX than PBI community). I really don't mind you tagging me for any future issues except stack doesn't allow user tagging but possible in the power bi community.

Comment: Good advice. Thanks again.